# HTML table code received from Python code not rendering

Tags: python, html, flask

I have Python code writing HTML code to a HTML file. This HTML file receives the code in a variable named `load1`.

```html
 <div id="load" class="load">
    
      {{ load1 }}
     
 </div>
```

On the browser, it displays the following:
[image: browser output]

Looking at the actual HTML file I see the following:
[image: htmlfile output]

The brackets `<` `>` is showing as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, etc

How can I actually see a table and not the HTML code as the final outcome?

Comment: {{ load1 | safe}}  <--- fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Flask, by default, protects any HTML in your variables.  You need to turn off autoescaping with the `{% autoescape xxx %}` command.

Here's the instructions:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/templating/